# my match command is creating new nodes instead of matching the relationship with existing nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a beginner and trying to learn NEO4J.

first, I executed the below query on NEO4J and it was successfully executed:

```
create(c:Company{CompanyCIN:"L01132WB1914PLC002502"})
create(d:Director{DirectorDIN:'434073'})
```

But when I run a query to match it or to make a relationship, it creates 2 new nodes.

```
match(c:Company{CompanyCIN:'L01132WB1914PLC002502'}),(d:Director{DirectorDIN:'434073'}) create (a)-[:Directed_by]->(b)
```

Can anyone please guide me, why this is happening in NEO4J?

[image: Here is the screenshot of the nodes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aliases in the CREATE statement (a and b) are different than those in the MATCH statement (c and d).

Just update the query to:

```
MATCH(c:Company{CompanyCIN:'L01132WB1914PLC002502'}),(d:Director{DirectorDIN:'434073'})
CREATE (c)-[:Directed_by]->(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

@julielinx's answer is valid, but if you run the query multiple times you will end up with multiple `Directed_by` relationships between those 2 nodes.

To avoid that, you should use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead of `CREATE`, as in:

```
MATCH (c:Company{CompanyCIN:'L01132WB1914PLC002502'}), (d:Director{DirectorDIN:'434073'})
MERGE (c)-[:Directed_by]->(d)
```